# Why is a MemberId get returned when I ask for PackageId?

Tags: sql, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.2

After creating the description model:

```
public class DescriptionModel
{
    [Key]
    public int DescriptionId { get; set; }

    public int PackageId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string DescriptionFull { get; set; }


    // Each description must be attached to 1 package
    [ForeignKey("PackageId")]
    public virtual PackageModel PackageModel { get; set; }

}
```

and the package model

```
public class PackageModel
{

    [Key]
    public int PackageId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Package Name")]
    [Required]
    public string PName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Location")]
    [Required]
    public string PLocation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MemberId")]
    public virtual AgentModel AgentModel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string MemberId { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<DescriptionModel> Descriptions { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Not reviewed")]
    public virtual ICollection<ReviewModel> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

I then use scaffolding to create a default controller and views. In the default "Create" view the PackageId is coming up as the authorised user's MemberID instead when I try.

```
@model final1.Models.DescriptionModel
...redacted create.cshtml...
div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="PackageId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="PackageId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PackageId"></select>
</div>
```

Above is the view which results in the label actually showing "PackageId" but the dropdown (ViewBag.PackageId) is actually the MemberID of the logged in user who's Package and Description it is.

How is my code erroneous?

[image: Related SQL database Tables]

Answer (score 0):

"ViewBag.PackageId" is the obvious answer, whereby MemberId should have been referred to.